# Request Headers intercept in QWebEngineView Qt creator

Tags: http, header, request, intercept

there is a need for interception of the created HTTP request and reading its HEADERS !. The Internet found it: [Capture server response with QWebEngineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309105/capture-server-response-with-qwebengineview), and it is impossible to access the headers that were generated on the page, but you can only insert your own. In this regard, I found the correct information only for the old QWebView, and QWebEngineView does not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question